# Настройка связи с помощью Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть основная таблица с записями, в проекте описана как следующий класс

```
public class Record 
{
   public int RecId { get; set; } //Идентификатор, primary key
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Так же есть вторая таблица, которая отображает связь "ребенок-родитель"

```
public class Relationship
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; } //Primary key
    public int ParentId { get; set; } //Foreign key
}
```

Нужно настроить связи в Entity Framework - у одного "ребенка" может быть только один "родитель", у "родителя" может быть несколько "детей". "Ребенок" также может быть родителем. Также возможна ситуация, когда у записи нет ни "родителя", ни "детей".

Comment: ту связь которую вы хотите можно реализовать при помощи [fluent-api](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/fluent-api-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: Зачем вам вообще 2 сущности? Просто добавьте в `Record` свойство `IEnumerable<Record> Children`. Либо Nullable-свойство `ParentId`

Comment: @АндрейNOP, я уже не вспомню, почему пришел к такому варианту. Скорее всего из-за того, что при формировании запроса мне надо подтягивать информацию о записях-"родителях" и записях-"детях" одновременно.

Comment: @Bald, знаю, но не умею. Какие в таком случае конфигурации писать и навигационные свойства в классах?

Comment: если изменение структуры таблиц возможно то вариант предложенный @АндрейNOP проще

Comment: @Ajmda, отлично, добавьте и `IEnumerable<Record> Children` и `int? ParentId` одновременно!

Comment: @АндрейNOP а если использовать fluent-api, то как описать такие связи?

Comment: Мне кажется, если добавить свойства `IEnumerable<Record> Children` и `Record Parent` (и `int? ParentId` если нужен), то даже ничего дополнительно настраивать с помощью FluentAPI не понадобится. Попробуйте.

Comment: @АндрейNOP не получилось, пришлось в конфигурации указать HasMany(m => m.Childrens).WithOptional(o => o.Parent).HasForeignKey(k => k.ParentId); Только есть проблема - если я захочу имя родителя, то как указать эту связь?

Comment: Из ребенка получить имя родителя? `myRecord.Parent?.Name`

Comment: @АндрейNOP работает, спасибо

Comment: Оформите ответом как решили свою задачу, чтобы топик не висел открытым

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убрал сущность Relationship, также изменил основную сущность Record следующим образом:

```
public class Record 
{
   public int RecId { get; set; } //Идентификатор, primary key
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int? ParentId { get; set; } //foreign key

   public Record Parent { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Record> Childrens { get; set; }
}
```

Также использовал [fluent-api](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/fluent-api-in-code-first.aspx) и при конфигурации написал следующие связи:

```
HasMany(m => m.Childrens).WithOptional(o => o.Parent).HasForeignKey(k => k.ParentId);
```